# How to make the sidebar stops scrolling after a certain point while main content beside the sidebar scrolls infinitely

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am building a Medium clone. In medium there is a main portion with a sidebar which shows suggested topics and all. When the sidebar reaches it's end it stops scrolling while the main content scrolls infinitely.

How to implement that in react Js?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Position sticky is the way